# what is the impact of limit in cassandra cql

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

When executing a cqlsh query like `select * from table limit 10`, would cassandra scan the entire table and just return the first 10 records, or it can precisely locate the first 10 records across whole datacenter without scanning the entire table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `LIMIT` option puts an upper-bound on the maximum number of rows returned by a query but it doesn't prevent the query from performing a full table scan.

Cassandra has internal mechanisms such as request timeouts which prevent bad queries from causing the cluster to crash so queries are more likely to timeout rather than overloading the cluster with scans on all nodes/replicas.

As a side note, the `LIMIT` option is irrelevant when used with `SELECT COUNT()` since the count function returns just 1 row (by design). `COUNT()` needs to do a full table scan regardless of the limit set. I've explained it in a bit more detail in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/6897/. Cheers!

Comment: Many thanks for your help. May I ask where is the documentation for `limit` option? I've read documentation for apache cassandra and datastax distribution of apache cassanra, and i didn't see the explanation you mentioned above.

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html

Comment: I found such explanation: `LIMIT can prevent a query from ranging over all partitions in a datacenter, or across multiple datacenters` . Doesn't this mean that  `limit` option can prevent full-table scan?

Comment: Even I have the same doubt regarding that. My first query will be limit, `select * from table_name limit 100`, after that I will pass the paging state got from the previous query resultset and do the same query again. Will this still do table scan? @Erick Ramirez

Comment: Huh. When do you actually need to fetch an entire table in reality?

Answer (score 2):

LIMIT option puts an upper-bound on the maximum number of rows returned by a query but it doesn't prevent the query from performing a full table scan.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. May I ask where is the documentation for `limit` option? I've read documentation for apache cassandra and datastax distribution of apache cassanra, and i didn't see the explanation you mentioned above